# Home-rolled Quicksort algorithm throwing stack overflow exception: finding next location of pivot in partition method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, quicksort

hey this is my quicksort code and its working for normal cases but not for those where the array have same elements and in that case i considered putting elements which are equal to pivot to the left side of pivot.Could anyone please rectify the logical mistake in my code:

```
public class Solution {

    public static int partition(int input[],int si, int ei) {
        int pivot = input[si],pivotPos = si,count = 0;
        // counting no of elements less than pivot so that  space can be left empty to left of pivot
        for(int i = pivotPos+1; i<input.length;i++) {
            if(input[i]<=pivot)
              count++;
        }
        //swapping pivot with the element
        input[si] = input[si+count];
        input[si+count] = pivot;
        pivotPos = si+count;
        // ensuring all elements to the left of pivot are less and to the right are more
        int i = si, j = ei,temp;
       
       while(i<pivotPos && j>pivotPos) {
        if(input[i]<=pivot)
        i++;
        else  {
            if(input[j]>pivot)
            j--;
            else {
                temp = input[i];
                input[i] = input[j];
                input[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
         }
       }
       return pivotPos;
    }

    public static void quickSort(int input[], int si, int ei) {
        if(si>=ei)
        return; 
        int pivotPos =  partition(input,si,ei);
        quickSort(input,si,pivotPos-1);
        quickSort(input,pivotPos+1,ei);
    }
    
    public static void quickSort(int[] input) {
        /* Your class should be named Solution
         * Don't write main().
         * Don't read input, it is passed as function argument.
         * No need to print or return the output.
         * Taking input and printing output is handled automatically.
         */
         quickSort(input,0,input.length - 1);
        
    }
    
}
```

input test case:
4 3 8 4 6 5
expected output:
3 4 4 5 6 8

my code gives stack overflow error from the point where partition function is being called

Comment: Why not use one of the numerous standard implementations that are already out there? This isn't one of them. Have a look at Knuth, or Sedgwick, or Wikipedia even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have fixed your code while making minimal changes to your code style. You'll notice that I left some of your code in even though it isn't what we actually need to do. I left that in for your comparison.

```
public class QuickSort {

    public static int partition(int input[],int si, int ei) {
        int pivot = input[si],pivotPos = si,count = 0;
        // counting no of elements less than pivot so that  space can be left empty to left of pivot

        for(int i = pivotPos+1; i<input.length;i++) {
            if(input[i]<=pivot) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        // the above var count is not the info we need
        // we need to know how many elements between si and ei (inclusive)
        // are less than the value of pivot

        // corrected logic here:
        int smallerThanPivotCount = 0;
        for (int i = si; i <= ei; i++) { // note that our logic includes ei
            if (input[i] < pivot)
                smallerThanPivotCount++;
        }


        //swapping pivot with the element
        input[si] = input[si + smallerThanPivotCount];
        input[si + smallerThanPivotCount] = pivot;
        pivotPos = si + smallerThanPivotCount;

        // next we are
        // ensuring all elements to the left of pivot are less and to the right are more
        int i = si, j = ei,temp;

        while(i<pivotPos && j>pivotPos) {
            if(input[i]<=pivot)
                i++;
            else  {
                if(input[j]>=pivot)
                    j--;
                else {
                    temp = input[i];
                    input[i] = input[j];
                    input[j] = temp;
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }
        return pivotPos;
    }

    public static void quickSort(int input[], int si, int ei) {
        if(si>=ei)
            return;
        int pivotPos =  partition(input,si,ei);
        quickSort(input,si,pivotPos - 1);
        quickSort(input,pivotPos+1,ei);
    }

    public static void quickSort(int[] input) {
        /* Your class should be named Solution
         * Don't write main().
         * Don't read input, it is passed as function argument.
         * No need to print or return the output.
         * Taking input and printing output is handled automatically.
         */
        quickSort(input,0,input.length - 1);
    }

}
```

I think your problem was just that you didn't correctly count the number of spaces forward you needed to shift the pivot. I have written code. I don't guarantee you 100% that it is correct, but it does pass my short list of unit tests, including your own example array. I suggest examining it yourself to understand the logic. Then clean up the extra stuff and make it your own. Cheers.

Comment: hey thank you so much for the reply also your logic is correct for the part where we need to include ei but in case of si we need to exclude si and initialize i with si+1 otherwise the code will give runtime error for every test case because si is already chosen as pivot and it would be just compare the element with itself.

Comment: @okiii I'm not sure I understood. Was that a question? Are you saying that my logic is incorrect somewhere?

Comment: @okiii After staring at your code for a bit, I think it's possible to make it work by changing just one character. In your original code in the count loop, if we write if(input[i]<pivot)``, then your sort function passes all my tests. The logic of it doesn't make sense to me, but somehow it works. However, if this were hw and I was grading it, I would ask you why you're counting all the elements <= pivot for the whole array after pivotPos+1 when the partition function should only be concerned with elements between si and ei. That is where your logic throws me.